# Did they remove the automatic user authentication from liftweb 2.0 snapshot?

Tags: lift

I just started a liftweb project and decided to go version 2.0 and it didn't seem to generate. Though I could be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got SBT ( http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/ ) and Git installed on your machine, try:

```
dpp@viper:~$ git clone git://github.com/dpp/lift_sbt_prototype.git
dpp@viper:~$ cd lift_sbt_prototype/
dpp@viper:~/lift_sbt_prototype$ sbt update ~jetty-run
```

Thanks